# regex validation in Meteor event

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor client code tries to allow only the correct phone number being typed. It is falling the the initial stage to get the correct console logs.
Please see the comments in the code.

Any idea? thx

```
Template.verify.events({
  'keyup #mobile': function (event) {
    let str = event.currentTarget.value;
    let pat = ValidationCol.findOne({key: 'mobileNum'}).regex;
    console.log(pat);   //<======= ^04[0-9]{8}$
    let reg = new RegExp(pat.source);
    console.log(reg);  // <========  /(?:)/
    if (reg.test(str)) {
      console.log('valid');   //<===== valid prints out with "d" input
    } else {
      console.log('not good');  //<=== suppose to print this instead.
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pat` holds the regex as a string, not an actual regex object. So the `.source` returns `undefined` and the `let reg = new RegExp(pat.source);` creates an empty regex that matches anything.

Use `let reg = new RegExp(pat);`